Unable to pass the custom attribute to brevo template using c#
I am trying to send an email using Brevo by having the existing template able to send the email but not able to see the updated property in the email. Here is my code
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string apiKey = "";

    // API endpoint for sending SMTP emails
    string apiUrl = "https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/smtp/email";

    // Example email data with template
    var emailData = new
    {
        sender = new { email = "a@a.com", name = "A" },
        to = new List<object> { new { email = "b@b.com" } },
        templateId = 1, // Template ID from Brevo
        **value = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "EMPLOYEENAME", "MYNAME" },
        }**
    };

    // Serialize email data to JSON
    string jsonData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emailData);

    // Create HTTP client instance
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        // Add API key to request headers
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("api-key", apiKey);

        try
        {
            // Create HTTP POST request
            var response = client.PostAsync(apiUrl, new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;

            // Check if request was successful
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Email sent successfully.");
            }
            else
            {
                string errorMessage = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to send email. Error: {errorMessage}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error sending email: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

I am trying to replace this but somehow it is not working
**value = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "EMPLOYEENAME", "MYNAME" },
            }**

This is my template builder 
This is what I added in my contact attributes

Adding the template design


I guess the reason of it is that you pass arguments into a template using value. You should pass them using params, atleast that is what documentations says.
So try something like it:
var emailData = new
    {
        sender = new { email = "a@a.com", name = "A" },
        to = new List<object> { new { email = "b@b.com" } },
        templateId = 1, // Template ID from Brevo
        @params= new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "EMPLOYEENAME", "MYNAME" },
        }
    };


When I am using params it it showing some error  Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Waste that i cannot connect to check it by myself (im getting unauthorized :) ), but maybe there is some very specific way of passing those parameters. It should work.

OK, I am unable to see the given name in the mail I received

@Developer it might be a problem with template- please verify that the placeholder has the same name as the key you send EMPLOYEENAME. Secondly verify  that placeholder in your email template is correctly formatted. You get any errors back from the API ?

@Bartisz no error from API I am receiving emails only problem is that replacing the EMPLOYEENAME. I added the template design

@Developer how it should know that EMPLOYEENAME that you give, is in contact object? Or, where in your code you initialize contact object?

So should I do some thing like this? dynamic transactionalParams = new
{
params = new
{
contact = new
{
EMPLOYEENAME  = "JohnDoe",
}
}
};

To be honest I never used that tool, i just entered documentation to answer your question. Find the way it should be done in documentation, and it should work fine :)

OK can you share the documentation that you read

https://developers.brevo.com/reference/getting-started-1
According to the documentation, you should use params.EMPLOYEENAME in your template.

I was able to read the content of template and replace it

@Developer if my answer solved your problem, consider accepting it.
